# Read file using urllib and write adding extra characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, carriage-return

I have a script that regularly reads a text file on a server and over writes a copy of the text to a local copy of the text file. I have an issue of the process adding extra carriage returns and an extra invisible character after the last character. How do I make an identical copy of the server file?

I use the following to read the file

```
for link in links:  
try:
    f = urllib.urlopen(link)
    myfile = f.read()
except IOError:
    pass
```

and to write it to the local file

```
 f = open("C:\\localfile.txt", "w") 

try:
    f.write(myfile) 
except NameError:
    pass
finally:
    f.close()
```

This is how the file looks on the server
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/inWfB.jpg

and this is how the file looks locally. Besides, an additional invisible character after the last 75
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW7xA.jpg

I have seen quite a few similar questions, but not sure how to handle the urllib to read in binary

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy a remote file denoted by a URL to a local file i would use urllib.urlretrieve:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://anysite.co/foo.gz", "foo.gz")
```

Comment: Thank you @RobertoAllende. I will try this. Just out of curiosity, will there be more network traffic with the method you have suggested or the read write method I had user previously?

Comment: If you are just doing one request to get a file, it might be the same in terms of network traffic, the problem is the issue you mention, strange characters and exception handling, exception handling so if you want to write a solid solution for this problem you would end up rewriting urlretrieve, which is available in the standard library and it is at least 60 lines long. So my suggestion is to reuse it and if you're interested on its implementation just check the source  code.

Answer (score 0):

I think urllib is reading binary.
Try changing

```
f = open("C:\\localfile.txt", "w")
```

to

```
f = open("C:\\localfile.txt", "wb")
```